# Is there any way to add a generic type parameter to a protocol?

Tags: objective-c, generics

As of Xcode 7, Objective-C introduced generic type parameters for classes. Is there any way to use generics with Objective C protocols? I haven't found an obvious way to do this because the equivalent to `@interface MyClass<ObjectType>` is already taken for protocols (e.g. `@protocol MyProtocol<NSObject>`).

Example: I would like to convert code like this:

```
@protocol MYObjectContainer
- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end
```

to code like this:

```
@protocol MYObjectContainer
- (ObjectType)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end
```

Which is possible with regular classes (see, for example, NSArray).

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Update your question with an example.

Comment: My guess is that you can't, because generics was added to classes in Objective-C to interface with Swift, and protocols in Swift don't have generics (they have associated types instead).

Answer (score 5):

If I correctly understand what you're saying you can:

Specify that the object should either be either an *instance of* or *inherit from* ObjectType by using:

```
@protocol MYObjectContainer
- (__kindof ObjectType *)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end
```

Specify that the *items in a collection* (NSArray, NSSet, etc.) should be an *instance of* ItemType (prefix with '__kindof' to also extend this to objects inheriting from ItemType) by using:

```
@protocol MYObjectContainer
- (CollectionType <ItemType *> *)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end
```

Note that Objective-C generics are designed to prevent hidden bugs by providing compiler warnings when a specified type is not adhered to. They do *not* actually force the specified type at runtime.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the answer. in the first option, where is ObjectType taken from? there is no such "type" or even pseudo-type.  In the second example (inheriting from ItemType) what is "CollectionType" ? and where is "ItemType" defined, or given as template? why would this even compile?