# Objective c protocol generics

Tags: objective-c, generics, objective-c-protocol

Can Objective-C protocol be generic?

Following [this tutorial](http://drekka.ghost.io/objective-c-generics/), I'm basically looking for something like that:

```
@protocol ItemsStore<__covariant ObjectType> <NSObject>

-(NSArray <ObjectType> *)items;

@end
```

Which is a generic protocol for some `ObjectType` that "implements" ("inherits") another protocol `NSObject`

Comment: FYI - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143194/is-there-any-way-to-add-a-generic-type-parameter-to-a-protocol

Comment: How on earth did that not come up on my search. Thanks

Comment: I don't think it makes sense. Marking a class as a generic covariant allows an instance of that class to qualify for the generic. However if you put it in a protocol the compiler doesn't know what you're intending to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @rmaddy suggested, and as referred to [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143194/is-there-any-way-to-add-a-generic-type-parameter-to-a-protocol), it is NOT possible.
Shame, moving to Swift then...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just redefine it as generic in the interface.

```
@protocol ItemsStore <NSObject>

- (NSArray *)items;

@end

@interface MyItemsStore<ObjectType> : NSObject <ItemsStore>

- (NSArray <ObjectType> *)items;

@end
```

This seems an unlikely scenario though. You might be better just defining the type of the items in each subclass. Like what Apple do with `NSFetchRequest` in their core data model generation.

Comment: just the syntax I was looking for. Can't have enough of 'em. Angle brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this question has exactly the same source problem as mine. Well, the idea of the design is great but doesn't work with ObjC. I also was wondering about that. I thought it could work some way like that:

```
@protocol Prototype<__covariant OtherProtocolOrClass> <NSObject>
/// Construct an object of the desired class or protocol
@property (nonatomic, nonnull, readonly) <OtherProtocolOrClass> objectFromPrototype;
@end
```

(I have not tested `@protocol Prototype <NSObject,__covariant OtherProtocolOrClass>` yet, but think it will fail.)

Another object in my framework (it is a collection) states, it can auto-construct an `NSArray<ObjectType>*` of an object type, if there is a Prototype that returns instances, like this:

```
@interface ValueProto : NSObject <Prototype<id<Value>>>
@end

@implementation ValueProto
-(id<Value>)objectFromPrototype {
    return [Value new];
}
@end
```

Im my dreams, the collection was constructed like this:

```
MyCollection<id<Value>>* const collection = [MyCollection new];
collection.prototype = [ValuesProto new];
```

And if you then access the collection's property, your array of `id<Value>` objects is constructed on the fly:

```
-(NSArray<id<Value>>*)values {
    NSArray*const sourceCollection = ...
    NSMutableArray<id<Value>>* const result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sourceCollection.count];
    for (id o in sourceCollection) {
        id<Value> v = self.prototype.objectFromPrototype;
        v.content = o;
        [result addObject:v];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Instead one of my class' objects must be the prototype itself:

```
-(id)objectFromPrototype {
    return [self.class new];
}
```

That clashes with my so-called 'Injector', which constructs and returns objects by protocols instead of classes.

If any Apple engineer is reading this:

Please, provide protocol covariants for ObjC. It's not yet dead! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use generic abstract class?

```
@interface AbstractItemStore <__covariant ObjectType> : NSObject

- (NSArray<ObjectType> *)items;

@end

@implementation AbstractItemStore

- (NSArray<id> *)items {
    NSParameterAssert("Not implemented!");
    return nil;
}

@end
```